# Angular scroll to anchor from another page

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a scroll to anchor button in angular.
I have been following this article:

https://medium.com/@navyjot/smooth-scroll-in-angular-c3e9942d23a1

Which works fine if I am currently on the page. This is my Html:

```
<a [ngClass]="class" [href]="button.href" [fragment]="button.fragment" data-category="navigate"
    data-action="internal link" mat-flat-button [color]="button.colour" (click)="scrollToElement($event)"
    *ngIf="button?.fragment && !external">
    {{ button.title }}
</a>
```

And the code I use is this:

```
public scrollToElement(e: MouseEvent): void {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(this.button.fragment);
}
```

Is it possible to get this to work from any page? Ideally to navigate to the "href" first, then to the "fragment"?

---

I tried with this:

```
public scrollToElement(e: MouseEvent): void {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (this.router.url === '/') {
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(this.button.fragment);
  } else {
    this.router
      .navigate([this.button.href])
      .then(() => this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(this.button.fragment));
  }
}
```

But that didn't work

Comment: is there a reason you're using an `a` tag instead of the `routerLink` directive? doesn't that reload your entire application?

Comment: That's irrelevant; I did it so I could "preventDefault" but still show a url when someone hovers over the link. I have tried with both :)

Comment: ah ok sorry too bad :(, anyways this way it's a bit difficult for me to help you I'm afraid, would it be possible to share your code or make a workable demo in something like stackblitz so that I could play around with it a bit?

Comment: Yeah, I will update the post once I have done it

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot :)